# How to override Foundation accordion styles?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation, accordion

I'm using foundation sites in a WordPress theme, I am trying to override the style for the accordion component:

In particular I want all the items to have a border-radius of 10px.

There seems to be a couple of mixins that apply specifically to the first and last elements on the list which change the border radius:

```
/// Adds styles for the accordion item. Apply this to the list item within an accordion ul.
@mixin accordion-item {
  &:first-child > :first-child {
    border-radius: $global-radius $global-radius 0 0;
  }

  &:last-child > :last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 $global-radius $global-radius;
  }
}
```

The problem I seem to be having is I am unable to override the borders in this mixin, I have tried re-declaring the mixin and changing the 0's to $global-radius.
I have changed the global Radius to 10px styles defined:

```
.di-accordian-title {
  background-color: $blue;
  color: $white !important;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.di-accordian-title:hover, .di-accordian-title:focus {
  background-color: $light-blue;
  color: $white !important;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

I just can't seem to override the first and last items border-radius.

This is my first time using sass in a project, first time using sass at all really.

What is the correct way to override the defaults set up in the accordion mixin?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to override the mixin, the specificity of your own styles or settings should override it.

There are two easy ways of doing this:

**Via "settings"**

In your `_settings.scss` file (which should be referenced from `app.scss`) there is a setting for `$global-radius` which by default is set to `0`. Simply set this to `10px` or `0.6rem` or whatever you fancy and the global radius will be changed to that amount.

*N.B. This is the radius for all foundation elements, not just the accordion.*

**Via specificity**

Alternatively if you want to keep a global radius of 0 (or whatever) and just want the accordion to have a 10px radius:

```
.my-accordion.accordion {
    .accordion-item {
        &:first-child > :first-child {
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        }

        &:last-child > :last-child {
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

This would go in one of your projects scss files, loaded after the Foundation SCSS, which are also `@import`ed from the `app.scss` file

Edit: Where `.my-accordion` is the class you have for that specific accordion, though it also works for all accordions if you just use the `.accordion-item` part of the scss above.

Comment: Thanks for this, i not had a chance to try this out yet, it looks very similar to what i had been trying to do previously and wasn't overriding the base style correctly.

Comment: I think that's because your CSS targets the `a` tag rather than the parent `li` (`.accordion-item`) where the border is set